# XSLT date functions on variables

Tags: xslt

Looking to extract the month from a date variable, then based on that digit, populate a separate field with a hard coded value.  Example: 
 When the date variable (effective date) has month '1'(1/23/2019) make END DATE '2/19/2019'.

Ive been able to narrow down the errors to `cannot compare xs:integer to xs:string`

```
<bsvc:End_Date>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="month-from-date(xs:date('$effectiveDate')) = '1'">
        <xsl:text>2/19/2019</xsl:text>
    </xsl:when>
</bsvc:End_Date>
```

Comment: Please post a reproducible example - see [mcve]. Note that `1/23/2019` is not a date in XSLT; a valid date must be in `YYYY-MM-DD` format. But you can use string functions to extract `1` from `1/23/2019` - e.g. `substring-before($effectiveDate, '/')`.

Answer (score 0):

If `$effectiveDate` contains a valid date, then the following expression:

```
<xsl:when test="month-from-date($effectiveDate) = 1">
```

(note the lack of quotes) will return true when the month of `$effectiveDate` is January.

---

**Demo**: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bnnZWg/1